# Tv out is not 16.9 only 4.3

Tags: resolution

I have intel gma 945 and when i tried to change the resolution to 1024x600 (16.9) it comes with error.

Note:At the moment it's setted on 800x600 (4.3),which gives you black borders and it's not full widescreen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the resolution first. use the following command on terminal.
to declare the needed resolution use..(copy and paste and enter it on terminal):

```
xrandr --addmode S-video 1024x600
```

Then to use the resolution copy, paste and enter the following command:

```
xrandr --output S-video --mode 1024x600
```